# How to handle user input/output in kdbg (testing assembly code)?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, kdbg

Read macro:

```
%macro read 2
  mov rax, 0  
  mov rdi, 0  
  mov rsi, %1 
  mov rdx, %2 i
  syscall
%endmacro
```

Write macro:

```
%macro write 2
  mov rax, 1  
  mov rdi, 0  
  mov rsi, %1 
  mov rdx, %2
  syscall
%endmacro
```

I'm trying to test my program by using kdbg, but I'm not sure on how to input something, as kdbg doesn't even prompt me to do so, and going to the output window when I try to write something to the `stdout` nothing is being displayed, what would be the correct approach to see my output or to input something from `stddin`?

Comment: for write, `stdout` is file descriptor 1, not 0.  Use `strace` to see what system calls you're actually making.  Make sure it works outside the debugger before you worry about `kdbg` and how it sets up a terminal emulator with your program's input / output connected to it.  e.g. are you sure you're passing a pointer to `read`/`write`, rather than a value?

Comment: After your suggestion it works fine in the terminal, but not sure on how to debug the program

Comment: In a terminal, FD 0 is connected to the TTY, so it might work to write to it.  But if there's a pipe, writing to FD 0 isn't going to work.  Use `strace`, and use the debugger to look at the return value in `rax` after `syscall`.

Comment: Also, while your program is running under `kdbg`, run (in another terminal) `ls -l /proc/PID/fd` (where PID is the pid of your process, not kdbg).  That will let you see whether stdin and stdout are connected to pseuto-terminals or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable interactive input, you have to use the external terminal window. Go to *Settings->This Program*, switch to the *Output* section, and enable *Full terminal emulation*. You have to reload the program. (It will be the top-most entry in *File->Recent Executables*.)

Comment: what should happen when I enable this option? How would I provide some input to the program?

Comment: When you reload the program, an `xterm` window will open, which is connected to stdin, stdout, and stderr of your program. Type your input in that window.